# convert pdf to jpeg on linux?

Tags: linux, pdf, jpeg

Sometimes clients email me a poster which they received from a graphic designer in pdf format that they want added to the site.  I have generally told them to ask the designer to export it in jpeg format.  This has been working out OK, but is there any easier option?  The only other way I have figured out is to do a screen shot of the pdf and then crop it using gimp, but that's kind of time consuming.

Comment: This is more appropriate on Superuser or perhaps the Ubuntu StackExchange site.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, Gimp should be able to import PDF files as read-only. So you just need to drag the PDF into Gimp and save-as JPEG.

Answer (score 3):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (and the [iMagick extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) if you're using PHP) should work reasonably well for this task.